# showing all search result in one template

Tags: wp-query, custom-taxonomy, woocommerce-offtopic, search

When I do a simple search(just ?s in the query) it shows the result in the search.php template.
but when I try to filter the result by custom taxonomies I created(for example ?s=text&brand=text) it shows the result over the taxonomy archive template I created and not over search.php.

Is there any way to show every search query result over the search template page?

EDIT: after investigating it a little bit further i think i know whats the problem. i think woocommerce takes control over the rewrite rules and give priority to their custom taxonomies. any idea how to fix this?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

solved it with this code

```
function prefix_url_rewrite_templates() {
    if ( get_query_var( 's' ) ) {
        add_filter( 'template_include', function() {
            return get_template_directory() . '/search.php';
        });
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'prefix_url_rewrite_templates' );
```

if there is a better way please notify me :)